# How to implement the "locking" mechanisme WITHOUT using mutex, futex and semaphore?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

So I need to implement the locking mechanism between threads in C.
Some sort of an alternative to:

```
pthread_mutex_lock 
pthread_cond_wait (mostly for synchronization)
```

For the pthread_cond_wait, I've done some research and found out that I can use Signals: sigwait, a liste for the waiting thread...

But I can't find a solution to lock the access to my shared variables and data between the threads.

Comment: sigwait etc. probably use those primitives internally anyway. In userspace you probably can't implement proper waiting without either spinning on some atomic variables. Pausing a thread usually requires you to have access to the operating system thread scheduler or other low-level privileged CPU instructions. What platform you are developing for?

Comment: I am working on Linux
EDIT: What about Compar and Swap? does it help in this situation?

Comment: Afaik you can't pause a thread in userspace in Linux. Eventually something needs to call the Linux kernel to suspend execution of your thread. The only alternative is to spin, using compare-and-swap or whatever other atomic primitives at your disposal.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need an alternative, is it for performance, for sake of exercise, or something else?

A [spinlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock) is an alternative to mutex but with no back-off mechanism, you'd have to busy-wait, which is usually not recomended. pthread mutex is implemented as a spinlock with a futex back-off.

pthread includes a no back-off [spinlock](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_spin_lock) so you don't have to write it yourself.

If it's only for an exercise, and you can call sleep, you can build something on that.

You can use a spinlock to lock some state management variables and simulate conditionals, semaphores, etc.